# Como crear modelo de eliminar y modificar datos

Tags: php

```
****<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css3/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<center><h3>LISTADO DE MATERIALES DEL ENCARGADO</h3></center>
 <div  class="E1" id="general">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tabla">
        <tr class="success">          
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th>Encardado : <?php echo $_SESSION['nombre'];?></th>              
          <th><a href="cerrarSeccion.php">Cerrar Seccion</a></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
 <section class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"><br><br>
 <a href="ingresoMaterial.php" class="btn btn-primary">Ingrese Un Material</a>
 <a href="../pdf/pdfReporte.php" class="btn btn-primary">Imprimir PDF</a>
    <div  class="E1" id="general">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tabla">
        <tr class="success">      
          <th>Materiales</th>
          <th>Descripcion</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
          <th>Precio</th>
          <th>Costo Total por Unidad</th>
          <th>Operacion</th>  
          <th></th>              
        </tr>
    <?php    
        include('../configuracion/conexion.php');
        $conexion = conectarse(); 
        $conector = " SELECT nombre, descripcion, cantidad, precio, cantidad*precio FROM materiales"; 
                $id= $_SESSION['id'];  
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$conector);
            $contador = 0;
            while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){   
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$row[0]</td>"; 
                echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";  
                echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";  
                echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
                echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";
                $contador = $contador + $row[4];

                  // ESTOS SON LOS BOTONES PERO NO SE SI SE USA ASI
                echo "<td>
                  <form method='POST' action='logicaEliminar.php'>
                    <button type='submit' name='$row[0]'>Eliminar</button>
                  </form>
                </td>";
                echo "<td>
                  <form method='POST' action='logicaCrudM.php'>
                    <button type='submit' name='$row[0]'>Modificar</button>
                  </form>
                </td>";   
                echo "</tr>";  
                }
                $conector2 = "UPDATE usuarios SET presupuesto='$contador' WHERE id='$id' ";    
                $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$conector2);


    ?>  
    </table>
    <div  class="E1" id="general">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tabla">
        <tr class="success">          
          <th>Presupuesto : <?php echo $contador;?> Bolivares</th>              
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>****
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias editar las pregunta y explicar el problema que tienes con el codigo, ya que asi como esta no queda muy clara la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Sólo veo código y uno que otro comentario dentro del código. Sería de mucha ayuda si al menos redactas el escenario y los intentos que has tenido. Saludos

Comment: el problema es hacer funcionar los botones para eliminar modificar  datos

Comment: Cuál es el problema con los botones? No envían el formulario? Por qué no usas enlaces y pasas los parámetros necesarios por GET?

Answer (score 1):

Se podría hacer de muchas otras formas (Ajax, un get directo al php para borrar/modificar) pero voy a ponerte el código para formularios que estás empleando.

En el formulario que metes para cada botón de borrar, te faltaría añadir un campo que recibiría el php `logicaEliminar.php`como parámetro, en el cual debes indicar el ID del elemento que hay que borrar.

```
<form method='POST' action='logicaEliminar.php'>
  <button type='submit' name='$row[0]'>Eliminar</button>
  <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?=$row['id'];?>'>
</form>
```

Además en el SELECT que lanzas contra la base de datos deberías sacar el ID o clave primaria de la tabla de cada elemento, para así poder introducirlo en el input hidden.

```
$conector = " SELECT ID, nombre, descripcion, cantidad, precio, cantidad*precio FROM materiales";
```

Faltaría revisar el código de logicaEliminar.php para ver como lo tienes.